# Trying to pass cursor value in function and return multiple value in string

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to pass a parameter in a function and use also use cursor value value in that function to return all multiple values  concatenated in string

i have a function name 'func_multi_val' whose return type is string inside that i am creating a cursor 'stage_val' .now getting value from these cursor i want to use in function loop wise and concatenating those values which return from function in strings.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE (cur_date in date)
  FUNCTION func_multi_val
    RETURN string 
  is 
  var_value string;
  BEGIN  
  cursor stage_val is 
 SELECT AGE_CD,
 decode(AGE_CD,'04','am,'05','bm','7u',NULL,AGE_DESC) AGE_DESC ,
 AGE_SEQ      
 FROM PROD_AGE_MST
 WHERE AGE_SEQ < 15
 AND AGE_CD NOT IN ('6A','05')
 ORDER BY 3

FOR i IN stage_val
    LOOP
SELECT Round(NVL(SUM(NVL(PROD_WT,0)),0),0) 
      INTO X
      FROM Prod_age_p_s_cur
      WHERE PSWF_DATE BETWEEN :PROD_DATE AND :PROD_DATE + 1
      AND PSWF_AGE_CD=:AGE_CD;
---how to concatenate value return from function in string?
End Loop 
return var_value
```

**Expected**: value return from function should be concatenate in a string

**Actual**:I am tying as shown above no idea about how to achieve it.

i am new to oracle. any idea would be appreciated

Comment: what are the values do you want to concatenate ?  please add sample data and desired output

Comment: @hotfix  data which i want to concatenate is number type i want to concatenate it  and then retrieve it at my client by removing concatenation.

Comment: As an aside, that `round(nvl(sum(nvl(prod_wt, 0)), 0), 0)` could be shortened to `round(nvl(sum(prod_wt), 0), 0)` - most aggregate functions (including `sum`) ignore NULL values, so you gain nothing by first converting them to 0 before doing the sum, and you do extra, unnecessary work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you should add this line at the end of your loop:

`var_value := var_value || var_value;`

like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_multi_val(cur_date in date) RETURN string is
  var_value string;
  cursor stage_val is

    SELECT AGE_CD,
           decode(AGE_CD, '04', 'am', '05', 'bm', '7u', NULL, AGE_DESC) AGE_DESC,
           AGE_SEQ
      FROM PROD_AGE_MST
     WHERE AGE_SEQ < 15
       AND AGE_CD NOT IN ('6A', '05')
     ORDER BY 3;
BEGIN
       FOR i IN stage_val LOOP
    SELECT Round(NVL(SUM(NVL(PROD_WT, 0)), 0), 0)
      INTO X
      FROM Prod_age_p_s_cur
     WHERE PSWF_DATE BETWEEN :PROD_DATE AND :PROD_DATE + 1

       AND PSWF_AGE_CD = :AGE_CD;
    --concatinating return string:
    var_value := var_value || var_value;
   END LOOP;
 return var_value;
END;
```

Please note that I made some syntax adjustments to make your code executable.

Comment: i want the value coming in variable this PSWF_AGE_CD = :AGE_CD; from cursor  'stage_val ' value AGE_CD

Comment: This still has multiple issues including undeclared variables and using bind variables.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple issues including:

- `decode(AGE_CD,'04','am,'05','bm','7u',NULL,AGE_DESC)` is missing a closing single quote.
- You need a length on the `var_value string;` declaration.
- The `CURSOR` should be declared before the `BEGIN`.
- There is no `:PROD_DATE` input or variable and you should not be using a bind variable; did you mean `cur_date`?
- `:age_cd` should not be a bind variable and probably should reference the cursor value using `i.age_cd`.
- You need a semi-colon on `END LOOP;`
- You need an `END;` statement to terminate the function.
- You have not declared the `X` variable.

Which would give you something like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_multi_val (cur_date in date)
  RETURN string
IS 
  var_value string(4000);
  x         string(40);

  CURSOR stage_val is
    SELECT AGE_CD
      FROM PROD_AGE_MST
     WHERE AGE_SEQ < 15
       AND AGE_CD NOT IN ('6A', '05')
     ORDER BY AGE_SEQ;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN stage_val LOOP
    SELECT Round(NVL(SUM(NVL(PROD_WT,0)),0),0)
    INTO   X
    FROM   Prod_age_p_s_cur
    WHERE  PSWF_DATE BETWEEN cur_date AND cur_date + 1
    AND    PSWF_AGE_CD= i.AGE_CD;

    var_value := var_value || ',' || x;
  END LOOP;

  return var_value;
END;
/
```

However, you do not need to use cursors and can just solve it in a single SQL statement that is not going to need to context-switch between SQL and PL/SQL:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_multi_val (cur_date in date)
  RETURN string
IS 
  var_value string(4000);
BEGIN  
  SELECT LISTAGG( total, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY rn )
  INTO   var_value
  FROM   (
    SELECT Round(NVL(SUM(NVL(c.PROD_WT,0)),0),0) AS total,
           rn
    FROM   Prod_age_p_s_cur c
           INNER JOIN (
             SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY AGE_SEQ ) rn,
                    AGE_CD
             FROM   PROD_AGE_MST
             WHERE  AGE_SEQ < 15
             AND    AGE_CD NOT IN ('6A','05')
             ORDER BY AGE_SEQ
           ) m
           ON ( c.PSWF_AGE_CD= m.AGE_CD )
    WHERE  c.PSWF_DATE BETWEEN cur_date AND cur_date + 1
    GROUP BY rn
  );

  return var_value;
END;
/
```

Which for the inputs:

```sql
CREATE TABLE prod_age_mst ( age_cd, age_seq, age_desc ) AS
  SELECT '04', 1, 'aa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '05', 2, 'bb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '7u', 3, 'cc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '6A', 4, 'dd' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE prod_age_p_s_cur ( prod_wt, pswf_date, pswf_age_cd ) AS
  SELECT 1, DATE '2019-07-22', '04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2019-07-22', '04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, DATE '2019-07-22', '05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, DATE '2019-07-22', '7u' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT func_multi_val( DATE '2019-07-22' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | FUNC_MULTI_VAL(DATE'2019-07-22') |
> | :------------------------------- |
> | 3,4                              |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=549333921ca1e6959d23e38ae053a604)*